# Customize Login Screen 18.04

Tags: login-screen, customization, desktop-background

How can i customize the login screen instead of having the normal ubuntu login screen?

Comment: in general there are not much things to customize login screen except changing the background for GNOME.. you can search and install different DM (Display Managers) and try..

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following command to open the css file in gedit.
**$ sudo gedit /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css**

Search for the term ‘lockDialog’ by pressing Ctrl+D and entering this keyword in the search bar. This way you will be directed to the location where we want to make the required changes.

### then replace the code as,

**#lockDialogGroup {
background: #2c001e url(file:///[fileLocation/filename.png]);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;

### }**

Answer (score 0):

### Enter the following command to open the css file in gedit.

$ sudo gedit /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css

Search for the term ‘lockDialog’ by pressing Ctrl+D and entering this keyword in the search bar. This way you will be directed to the location where we want to make the required changes.

### then replace the code as,

## lockDialogGroup {

background: #2c001e url(file:///[fileLocation/filename.png]);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
}

---

Replace the [fileLocation/filename.png] part with the location and filename of the image you want to use as the new background.
Save this file by clicking the Save button located at the top right corner of the text editor.

Restart your computer for these changes to take effect.